# Send Android Notifications while not on App

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I have Notifications working for when a user clicks on a button. I am looking to send this notification without the user clicking on this button and without being on the app.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Here is my button that is getting the toast from the Broadcast Receiver:

```
public void onetimeTimer(View view){
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
if(alarm != null){
    alarm.setOnetimeTimer(context);
}else{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here is my Alarm Manager Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

final public static String ONE_TIME = "onetime";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
//Acquire the lock
wl.acquire();

//You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
 msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
}
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
// msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

    //msgStr.append();

Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Release the lock
wl.release();
```

}
Here is the method in the Broadcast receiver:

```
public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context){
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
   intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.TRUE);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
   }
```

Here is the Notification that is working behind a button that I would like to be set off by the alarm manager without the button being pressed.

```
Button btnNotifyWorkout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNotifyWorkout);
        btnNotifyWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent();
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(HomeActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                                            .setTicker("TickerTitle")
                                            .setContentTitle("Lukes App")
                                            .setContentText("You have a workout due today")
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();

                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                NotificationManager nm  = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(0, noti);
            } 
        });
```

Comment: Ok cool how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but I am assuming you want to generate the notification when an alarm is triggered?

You can move the notification notify to the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver.

Did you declare that receiver in your manifest?